# No service for type T has been registered WebApi 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Trying to inject in my controller a repo but it's not working and I keep getting the same error. This is how I'm doing.

The Interface

```
public interface IGeneral
{
    Task<Message> RegisterAsync(UserModel model);
}
```

The Context

```
public abstract class BaseRepository
{
    protected readonly Context Context;

    public BaseRepository(Context context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public class General : BaseRepository, IGeneral
{
    public General(Context context) : base(context) {}

    public async Task<Message> RegisterAsync(UserModel model)
    {
        var result = await Context.User.Where(a => a.Email == model.Email).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if(result != null)
        {
            await Context.User.AddAsync(new Data.Access.Models.User 
            { Date = DateTime.Now, Email = model.Email, Name = model.Name, Password = model.Password });
            await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return Message.Exists;
    }
}
```

The Implementation

```
[HttpPost("Register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromServices] General general, UserModel userModel)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(await general.RegisterAsync(userModel));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<IGeneral, General>();
```

And the Exeption that I get from Postman!

> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Mangue.Api.Services.Repository.General' has been registered.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ServicesModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: You inject an instance of `General`, not `IGeneral`. If you add the I it might work :)

Comment: Omg, how can I miss that!

Comment: No problem :) I'll add an answer so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You register a service of type `IGeneral` (which resolves to `General`) but you request an instance of `General` instead of `IGeneral`.
Change `General` to `IGeneral` in the `Register` function and it'll work.